# How to Embed Javadoc in a Jar for Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, javadoc

Is it possible to automatically embed javadoc into a jar from NetBeans? In the program there is an option to generate javadoc. This creates a finished website generated from the existing javadoc in your project. There is also an option to attach javadoc to a project or jar so that it shows up in the suggestions. Right now, when I click build and then take the jar and add it to a project on a different computer the javadoc for jar does not show up. I have to manually copy it over to the computer and attach it, which seems redundant when I should just be attached automatically.

Things I tried:

- Using 'Clean and Build' and just 'Build'
- Exporting the whole dist folder instead of just the jar.
- Putting the javadoc inside the jar.

Comment: You'd have to modify the build.xml to provide this functionality. There's a ['javadoc`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) ant which can be used to generate the docs

Comment: @MadProgrammer How do I do that? I am looking under the build tab in project properties and I can't see anything related to javadoc. I also have the build.xml file open but I don't know what to put in for the javadoc.

Comment: No, you need to go to the "Files" tab (next to the "Projects" tab), expend your project node and you will see the `build.xml` file, you can open this (in Netbeans) and you will need to add your modifications to it.  This a little bit of information available there with some ideas on how to modify the build process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the default Ant based Netbeans Project, you will need to modify the projects `build.xml` file to include the generation of the JavaDocs and copy the resulting files into the `build.classes.dir` so they can be Jar'ed

Start by clicking on the `Files` tab, next to the `Projects` tab, expand your project node and you will see the `build.xml` file in the root directory

[image: Files Tab]

Next, the you need to inject some functionality into the build process, between the compile and jar processed.  Reading through information inside the `build.xml`, the `-post-compile` target is probably the place we want to get started.

After having a read of [the `javadoc` ant task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html), I added this to my `build.xml`

```
    <target name="-post-compile">
        <javadoc 
            sourcepath="src"
            defaultexcludes="yes"
            destdir="javadocs"
            author="true"
            version="true"
            use="true"
            windowtitle="The name of your API"
        >
            <doctitle><![CDATA[<h1>My API</h1>]]></doctitle>
            <bottom><![CDATA[<i>Copyright &#169; 2000 Dummy Corp. All Rights Reserved.</i>]]></bottom>
            <tag name="todo" scope="all" description="To do:"/>
            <link offline="true" href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/" packagelistLoc="C:\tmp"/>
            <link href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/"/>                
        </javadoc>
        <copydir src="javadocs" dest="${build.classes.dir}/javadocs"/>
    </target>
```

So, I placed this directly under `<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>` in the `build.xml` file, but it's placement should matter.

This generated a jar file with the `javadocs` directory (and the javadocs) included in it

Comment: Sorry I am kinda confused. Should this be in the `build-impl.xml` in `nbproject` or `build.xml` in the project folder?

Comment: As I said, *"I added this to my `build.xml`"*, the build-impl.xml is auto generated by netbeans and you shouldn't modify it

Comment: Sorry, the image is misleading, I'll endeavour to update it